# Removing Content-Type header in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I have the following code in .Net Core:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Dropbox-API-Arg", GenerateJsonFromObject(new {path = filePath}));
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download");
    var result = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
}
```

As you can see it's quite simple piece of code and it works correctly, but only on Windows.
When I'm running the same code on my Linux VPS (Ubuntu 16.04 server with .Net Core 1.0.4) I'm receiving the following error message from Dropbox API:

```
Error in call to API function "files/download": You provided a non-empty HTTP "Content-Type" header ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").  This API function requires that the header be missing or empty.
```

So API requires empty or null Content-Type Header, but somehow in .Net Core this header is automatically added to my request.

The result of printing request headers is the same on Windows and on Linux:

```
Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/tracklogs/night_ride.gpx"}
}
```

So my question is:
How to avoid adding Content-Type header automatically by .Net Core?

What I've tried:

1 Set an empty Content-Type header:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "");
```

Won't work, even if I set value of header to "application/json" it's automatically changed to application/x-www-form-urlencoded :(

2 Remove whole header:

```
request.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
```

or:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Content-Type");
```

In both cases I'm receiving the following exception:

```
Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448733/as3-sending-empty-content-type-header-in-urlrequestheader

Comment: @Boggin it's not a duplicate - as you can read, i've tried to set Header value to application/json (and even to space), but .net core somehow overrides this and it's changing the value.

Comment: You need to update your question as it does not state you tested with a space character.

Comment: Linked question is not about .Net. But option with space still cando work.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a POST. This adds a default content-type for the normally required body.

It's not clear if the specification mandates a body but this the point of a POST over a GET, and is sometimes implemented as required (although of course it might be a blank). In view of this, I suspect .net always adds a content-type header to give that body meaning. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-method-definitions

Possibly this request should be a GET which doesn't require a body. There may also be alternative ways to make the request which give more control over the construction of the request.